# How to sort some specific element in an array using comparator

Tags: java

I am trying to sort an array in a specific order. if number % 10 is equal 0 then it will come first and for the rest, if number mod 10 is greater it will come first.

```
Collections.sort(arr,new Comparator<Integer>(){
   public int compare(Integer e1, Integer e2) {
       if(e1 %10 == 0 && e2 %10 != 0  || (e2 %10 == 0 && e1 %10 != 0)  
       || e1 % 10 ==0 || e2 % 10 ==0){
           return -1;
       }else{
           if(e1 % 10 < e2 % 10){
               return 1 ;
           }else{
               return -1 ;
           }
       }
   }});
```

input : [120, 20, 35, 7, 29]

output: [29, 7, 35, 20, 120]

expected: [120, 20, 29, 7 , 35]

Comment: A comparator should always be able to return zero. At a minimum, equal inputs should return zero.

Comment: You said if `number % 10 == 0` it will not come first.  Then why does 120 come first in your expected answer?

Comment: This condition is confused:  ```(e1 %10 == 0 && e2 %10 != 0  || (e2 %10 == 0 && e1 %10 != 0)  
       || e1 % 10 ==0 || e2 % 10 ==0)```.   Consider e1 = 10, e2 = 20.  Neither of the first two terms ("only one input is a multiple of 10") will be true.  But then the last two terms ("one input is a multiple of 10 regardless of the other") will be true.  That if statement therefore reduces to ```if (e1 % 10 ==0 || e2 % 10 ==0)``` which implies 10 < 20 and 20 < 10.

Comment: Furthermore, it is not valid for a comparator to return inconsistent results such as 10<20 and 20<10: [link to documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-).

Comment: @another-dave Actually i dont need to sort the number which are multiple of 10 . I just need to arrange them at first in any order .. I need to sort others which are not multiple of 10 and i need to sort by their last element and in descending order ..as i have given expected  : 120 20 29 7 35 ..It can be 20 120 29 7 35 . The input is 120 20 35 7 29 so , first two are already in sorted in that case ...I need to sort in the both case ...I think i explained in a better way now ..

Comment: @WJS that was a mistake ..extremely sorry for that ..I've corrected it

Comment: @another-dave I have got your point on inconsistency. It should return 0 rather than -1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comparator which return 0 indicates that the values are equal and nothing need to be switched. In your case, we have the say in the compare method, that the first if should return 0. This will give you the wanted result.

```
Collections.sort(arr, new Comparator<Integer>() {
    public int compare(Integer e1, Integer e2) {
        if (e1 % 10 == 0 && e2 % 10 != 0 || (e2 % 10 == 0 && e1 % 10 != 0) || e1 % 10 == 0 || e2 % 10 == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            if (e1 % 10 < e2 % 10) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.lang.*; 
import java.io.*; 
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(120);
        list.add(20);
        list.add(35);
        list.add(7);
        list.add(29);

        Collections.sort(list,new Comparator<Integer>(){
           public int compare(Integer e1, Integer e2) {
               if(e1 %10 == 0  || e2%10 == 0){
                   return 1;
               }
               else {
                   if(e1 % 10 > e2 % 10){
                       return -1 ;
                   }else{
                       return 0 ;
                   }
               }
           }});

           Iterator<Integer> myListIterator = list.iterator(); 
           while(myListIterator.hasNext()) {
               System.out.println(myListIterator.next());
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: This also has the property that 10 < 20 and 20 < 10.  The result of ```compare(10,20)``` is 1, so 10 > 20.  The result of ```compare(20,10)``` is 1, so 20 > 10.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this with an explicit comparator is:

```
public int compareTo(Integer a, Integer b) {
  int cmp = Boolean.compare(a % 10 != 0, b % 10 != 0);
  if (cmp != 0) {
    return cmp;
  }
  return a.compareTo(b);
}
```

Using `Boolean.compare(a % 10 != 0, b % 10 != 0)` finds if the last digit is zero or not: if `a` does not end with zero but `b` does, a positive value is returned, so `a` will be sorted after `b`.

If the either both end with a zero, or neither ends with a zero, the numbers are compared naturally.

Comment: this is helpful but i dont need natural compare . which are mod by 10 will be placed first .. and others will be placed by their last digit descending order .. As like the expected output given :  120 20 29 7 35 .... from your code i am getting 20 120 7 29 35

Comment: Then you could simply use `return Boolean.compare(a % 10 != 0, b % 10 != 0);`. However, you would then be violating [consistency with equality](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). This would lead to likely unexpected behavior if you were to use this Comparator with a `TreeSet`. Given that you haven't got a defined ordering for the elements within the "mod 10 == 0" and "mod 10 != 0" classes, it is best to impose an arbitrary ordering which meets the contract of the interface.